# MVC Best way to display charts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mschart

I'm Newbie and now i'm trying to display charts with MVC.

There are two possibilities to show charts:

1. System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
2. System.Web.Helpers.Chart

Which is the different between this two solutions?  And what the advantage / disadvantage between?

At the moment, i try this code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RenderRainfallChart()
    {
        var incomeList = Income.GetList();
        List<string> xValue = new List<string>();
        List<decimal> yValue = new List<decimal>();

        foreach (var item in incomeList)
        {
            xValues.Add(item.Name);
            yValues.Add(item.Amount);
        }

        var key = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddSeries(
                legend: "IncomeLIst",
                xValue: xValue,
                yValues: yValues)
            .Write();}
```

After my button selection, the chart will be shown on a new broswer page: .../Company/RenderRainfallChart

Is it possible, to show the chart in a div-container on the index-site?

Answer (score 0):

Google chart API maybe? It uses JavaScript so you would have to either write the values in the page or retrieve them with AJAX.

Comment: Your working with MVC no? 99% of the time a server will have an active Internet connection

Answer (score 0):

For a non-interactive chart, you can make one GET for getting the image for the chart and then in your web page you can simply put an `<img>` that points to that URL.

You can get the bytes for the chart image using something like this:

```
byte[] GetBytes(Chart chart, ChartImageFormat imageFormat)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        chart.SaveImage(stream, imageFormat);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```